# getrawinputdata within a simple main()

Tags: c++, keyboard, hid, raw-input

I am trying to read values from the joystick using simple C++ techniques and Windows.
My aim is to write a program that sends a keyboard command whenever the joystick signal exceeds a predefined threshold. The keyboard command will be picked up by whichever window would be active at the time.

My C++ coding skills are limited so I wish to do this in the simplest way, preferably within one main().

Up to now I have managed to register the joystick.

But I stumbled across the first problem, which is how to use GetRawInputData(). I found a lot of examples about this within a win32 structure, but am struggling to translate this to a simple main().

My code till now is the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];

int main()
{
    UINT      bufferSize;

    Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid[0].usUsage = 0x05;
    Rid[0].dwFlags = 0;
    Rid[0].hwndTarget = 0;

    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE)
    {
        std::cout << "Registration failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Registration OK" << std::endl;

        while (1)
        {
            // This is the part in which I would like to read the joystick values
            // and determine whether to send a keyboard event or not.
        }


    }

    return 0;

}
```

Can you help?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion to use joyGetInput(), here is the updated code:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

#define mid 32767
#define trig 1804
#define reset 1475

int main()
{

    JOYINFO pos;

    UINT result;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    INPUT xi, yi, zi;

    int i = 0;
    int state[6] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int uu = mid + trig;
    int ul = mid + reset;

    xi.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    yi.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    zi.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    while (1)
    {
        result = joyGetPos(i, &pos);

        if (result != JOYERR_NOERROR)
        {
            cout << "JoyID " << i << " returned an error. Trying the next one." << endl;
            i++;
            if (i > 15)
            {
                cout << "Reached the maximum allowed attempts. Exiting." << endl;
                return 1;
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            //GetSystemTime(&st);

            //cout << st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute << ":" << st.wSecond << ":" << st.wMilliseconds <<  "\tX: " << pos.wXpos << "\tY: " << pos.wYpos << "\tZ: " << pos.wZpos << endl;

            if (pos.wXpos > uu && state[0] == 0)
            {
                xi.ki.wVk = 0x30;
                xi.ki.dwFlags = 0;
                SendInput(1, &xi, sizeof(INPUT));
                state[0] = 1;
                GetSystemTime(&st);
                cout << "Key down - X axis" << endl;
                cout << st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute << ":" << st.wSecond << ":" << st.wMilliseconds << "\tX: " << pos.wXpos << "\tY: " << pos.wYpos << "\tZ: " << pos.wZpos << endl;
            }
            if (pos.wXpos < ul && state[0] == 1)
            {
                xi.ki.wVk = 0x30;
                xi.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &xi, sizeof(INPUT));
                state[0] = 0;
                GetSystemTime(&st);
                cout << "Key up - X axis" << endl;
                cout << st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute << ":" << st.wSecond << ":" << st.wMilliseconds << "\tX: " << pos.wXpos << "\tY: " << pos.wYpos << "\tZ: " << pos.wZpos << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My new question now is:
How do you simulate a long key press? I would like the target window to behave just like a user kept pressing on the key. With the above code, the key is issued only once.

Comment: No need to import the whole `std` namespace so that you can use `cout` without `std::` prefix

Answer (score 1):

[`GetRawInputData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645596.aspx) takes an `HRAWINPUT` handle as input.  The only place you can get that handle is from the `LPARAM` parameter of the [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) window message.

Your `main()` function needs to use `CreateWindow/Ex()` to create a window (if you don't want the user to see it, consider making a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only)), specify that window in the joystick's `RAWINPUTDEVICE::hwndTarget` field when you call [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600.aspx), and then run a message loop so the window can receive messages.  For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wx.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wx.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wx.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyRawInputWndClass");

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wx))
    {
        std::cout << "Window Class Registration failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wx.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, wx.hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        std::cout << "Window Creation failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid = {};
    Rid.usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid.usUsage = 0x05;
    Rid.dwFlags = 0;
    Rid.hwndTarget = hWnd;

    if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(&Rid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)))
    {
        std::cout << "Device Registration failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Device Registration OK" << std::endl;

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_INPUT)
        {
            HRAWINPUT hRawInput = reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(msg.lParam);
            // retrieve and process data from hRawInput as needed...
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (Msg == WM_INPUT)
    {
        HRAWINPUT hRawInput = reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam);
        // retrieve and process data from hRawInput as needed...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wx.lpfnWndProc = &MyWndProc;
    wx.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wx.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyRawInputWndClass");

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wx))
    {
        std::cout << "Window Class Registration failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wx.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, wx.hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        std::cout << "Window Creation failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid = {};
    Rid.usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid.usUsage = 0x05;
    Rid.dwFlags = 0;
    Rid.hwndTarget = hWnd;

    if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(&Rid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)))
    {
        std::cout << "Device Registration failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Device Registration OK" << std::endl;

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you read the [Raw Input documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) more carefully.  This is all explained in detail.  If you don't specify a window to `RegisterRawInputDevices()`, the OS will send the `WM_INPUT` messages to whichever window currently has the keyboard focus, which is not what you want.

That being said, if you want something simplier, you might consider using [`joyGetPosEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757108.aspx) instead of Raw Input.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion to use joyGetPos(). It is now working as I would like it to. The new code is updated in my original post.

My new question now is: how do you simulate a long press?

Comment: @JayD simply put a delay in between key down and key up.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. A delay does not work. It will only display the key once.